# MSI GTX 960 oc broken capacitor

Tags: soldering, capacitor

I accidentally broke one of the tiny capacitor that is connected right next to the PCIe bus but thank god the card still works but only runs at x4 instead of x16.

I have a soldering station and I have basic skills of soldering electric components.

I want to fix it but I don't know the uf and voltage of that cap for replacement.

I searched online for the PCB diagram or schema but I couldn't find anything.

I am asking an expert to recommend me the values of the capacitor that I should buy.

[image: Here is a picture of the missing capacitor]

Comment: You are not likely to find the (copyrighted) circuit diagram.  Take it to a local shop and try may be able to tell you the replacement specifications

Comment: It's likely the same as the one next to it. Can't you detach the one next to it and look for a capacitance value on the can?

Comment: Trying to solder such a tiny component while not impossible, is quite tricky. Also judging by the blurry picture isn't the top solder pad damaged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are going to be the AC coupling capacitors for the PCIe TX lanes. From some random PCIe device on the internet:

[image]

They claim to be ".1uF" so 100nF. Its hard to judge from an image but the size there could be 0402 so you are looking for an 0402 100nF capacitor.

You will need a very *very* fine soldering iron tip.

The value will be from the PCIe spec and from experience is going to be the same across all PCIe devices.

Typically they are kept close to the transmitter side, the RX lines simply have 0 ohm links and their AC coupling capacitors will be near the other device in the PCIe connection, either the CPU or PCH.

Answer (score 1):

As @spikey_richie suggests, you the actual value. If possible, examine it with a low-power microscope, since *some* [multilayer ceramic capacitors](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/smd-smt-surface-mount-capacitor.php) have the value printed on them.

Removing and replacing surface mount devices (SMD) is nontrivial. If you do not have [micro-soldering equipment](https://www.microsoldering.com/tools-and-equipment/), nor know someone who does, it is possible, though difficult, to replace a SMD cap, or even substitute a slightly larger component with leads, with just magnifier, *fine* point soldering iron and tweezers. In that position, at an input or output, the value of the cap and lead length would not be as critical as in a timing cap, so a slight mismatch would likely have little impact on actual throughput.

Consider cost of professional repair, and price of a new board, and this *might* be a cost-effective experiment... or not. Though I've replaced broken SMD diodes on a keyboard with leaded ones, and it works well, it is a less critical application.